# How to fix LONG urls in magento for Layered navigation. SEO Practice

Tags: php, magento, seo, magento-1.4

According to some SEO Practices having long URL is not good.

Magento uses layered navigation and when you have lots of attributes then the URL becomes very very long.

I can not put an URL here because the moderatos say its too localized.

I just wanted to know if this is possible to fix using any kind of code?
As I am not an expert on magento or php, I can not provide any code because I dont even know where should I start looking for to fix this.

Somebody suggested editing filter.phtml and put rel=nofollow.

Is it a good practice?  Is it recommended that search engines dont crawl those pages that are related to layered navigation?
Another problem they have is that the title and description its always the same.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you read YOAST Magento SEO article?
[YOAST Magento SEO](http://yoast.com/articles/magento-seo/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the technical solution:

1. Copy filter.phtml from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer` to the equivalent directory in your site's theme.
2. In the anchor tag there (should be only one) add a `rel="nofollow"` attribute.

However, I would expect first that a SEO expert tell us if this should be done this way or not.

Comment: thank you, I would expect, if I dont hear a seo expert in a few hours, I will use your solution.

Comment: This is a word-for-word copy of my own answer from the original attempt at this question, which was [removed on a technicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114229). I'm not petty about it, just sad. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a `rel="canonical"` to point back to the main category that lists all of your products, that way more "juice" is sent back to that page for ranking.

More on that here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394

Another solution would be to add the site to Google Webmaster Tools and then adjust how Google treats certain query string variables.  By default, Google (and presumably others) examine pages with certain query string variables and try to determine if the page is different enough to rank separately or only rank the most relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your post, for help I created a module that solves this error.

https://github.com/jruzafa/Devopensource_LayerCatSeo